# Command Line Arguments during Runtime

Tags: c++

In the program I am writing it takes arguments from the command line, then does computations with them. Once the program finishes it prompts the user whether they want to run again. If the user clicks yes, it should rerun.

Usually a while(condition) loop would work but in this case since the arguments come from the command line, how can I grab new ones during run-time?

Comment: ***Show Code***

Comment: You mean, like, get user input at runtime...?

Comment: There's only one set of command-line arguments, the user can't change them after the program starts. Maybe the program should prompt for input instead of getting them from the command line.

Comment: May be use shell script which runs the program in a loop and asks for user input once the program ends

Comment: that sounds worth trying, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments come in from `argc/argv`.

User input comes in via input functions like `cin`, `scanf` or `fgets`.

There is no reason you cannot use both methods of gathering input.

***What exact problem are you having?***
*(show your code)*

Comment: This issue is if I ask for input in the program explicitly in a loop it'll ask during the first run. Yet, the first run's args are from the command line.

Comment: That is what an `if` statement is for:  `if (input already provided) { /* skip gathering more input */ }`

Comment: Or get the first arguments from `args` outside the loop and once inside the loop get the remainder from `std::cin`.